# How to solve "dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libvdpau1_1.1.1-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb"

Tags: apt, updates, dpkg, 64-bit

I'm having trouble with the update manager. 
Normal install gets me:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ffmpeg : Depends: libvdpau1 (>= 0.2) but it is not installed
mesa-vdpau-drivers : Depends: libvdpau1 but it is not installed
vdpau-va-driver : Depends: libvdpau1 (>= 0.2) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

with the recommended option:

```
~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
 libvdpau1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 libvdpau1
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/25,5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 100 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 235502 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libvdpau1_1.1.1-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvdpau1:amd64 (1.1.1-3ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libvdpau1_1.1.1-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/etc/vdpau_wrapper.cfg', which is different from other instances of package libvdpau1:amd64
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libvdpau1_1.1.1-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Has anyone got any idea what the problem might be? I've tried all solutions to similar problems on here and none is working.

Comment: Have you tried removing `libvdpau1` first?

Comment: Run `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libvdpau*` and `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to overwrite ... which is different from other instances of package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855474/trying-to-overwrite-which-is-different-from-other-instances-of-package)

Answer (score 2):

-Remove the vdpau_wrapper.cfg file & do the force install

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/vdpau_wrapper.cfg

sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove libvdpau1

sudo apt-get -y install libvdpau1
```

Then I installed the package which was blocked.