# Can't install anything from software center

Tags: package-management, software-center

I'm trying to install the Synaptic package manager, but the installation fails due to

`Unable to install "Synaptic Package Manager": Error whiles installing package: trying to overwrite shared '/usr/bin/unity-scope-loader', which is different from other instances of package libunity9`

The same error also comes up regardless of what program I try to install from the software center.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Also please add output of `apt-cache policy synaptic libunity9` and `dpkg -S /usr/bin/unity-scope-loader`, `apt-get install --simulate synaptic` to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to overwrite ... which is different from other instances of package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855474/trying-to-overwrite-which-is-different-from-other-instances-of-package)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to install from a terminal? open a terminal and type the command

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

You will then be asked for password for authentication. Enter password and Synaptic will install. I believe you will find Synaptic easier to work with.
Software center seems to have issues in 16.04 as well.

Edit - after a bit of research (should have done in 1st place - sorry) I discovered the correct command to install from terminal. give this a try.

Comment: that doesn't work either. Here's what shows up regardless of what app i try to get via terminal "sudo apt install synaptic-package-manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package synaptic-package-manager"

Comment: There is no [`synaptic-package-manager` package on all Ubuntus](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=synaptic-package-manager). Consider removing your "answer".