# Dependency error after attempting to install realtech audio drivers

Tags: apt, package-management, sound, dpkg

I tried to get drivers from realtech but this was not working, so I went to the ALSA project page https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Main_Page and attempted to install `alsa-lib-1.2.4` and `alsa-utils-1.2.4` as instructed by the README. Now when ever i try to use apt i get a broken pip error.

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-libc-dev:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-libc-dev:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
24 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,138 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,965 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 233231 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-libc-dev_5.4.0-52.57_i386.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:i386 (5.4.0-52.57) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-libc-dev_5.4.0-52.57_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/include/sound/asequencer.h', which is different from other instances of package linux-libc-dev:i386
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-libc-dev_5.4.0-52.57_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Yes this worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue:

[Trying to overwrite ... which is different from other instances of package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855474/trying-to-overwrite-which-is-different-from-other-instances-of-package)

Thank you https://askubuntu.com/users/94914/karel