# Unable to Update ( Facing issue with LibC6 package) (20.10)

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

I'm trying to update my system to get 21.04 but I'm facing some issues when trying to update

on running sudo apt upgrade
I get

**Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).**

on running sudo apt --fix-broken install
I get

**dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.32-0ubuntu3_i386.
deb (--unpack)

trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libc6/NEWS.Debian.gz', which is   different from other instances of package libc6:i386

Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.32-0ubuntu3_i386.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**

on trying to install libc6 (sudo apt-get install libc6:i386)

I get

**You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libc6:i386 : Depends: libcrypt1:i386 (>= 1:4.4.10-10ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libnss-nis:i386 but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libnss-nisplus:i386 but it is not going to be installed
locales :

Depends: libc-bin (> 2.33)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).**

Any help will be really appreciated I'm kind of stuck here rn

Comment: You've made it difficult to read, I had a quick look at editing and adding {code} blocks, but your pastes don't have \n or line-breaks so it's won't really be any more readable.  Ubuntu 20.10 is EOL (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/) and the package tools have already dropped the capacity to look up details for *groovy* (you're too late), so the likely only on-topic response now is to *upgrade via re-install*.  You haven't said if desktop/server, but it's actually easy on desktop (which I gather you're using).

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   *You do mention an intention of upgrading, but your question is about 20.10 and not the release-upgrade step; if you'd upgraded before EOL we could look up issues, but you're too late for the support you need*

Comment: Hey thank you for taking the time to reply; I am intending to upgrade to 21.04 (from 20.10)  and am on Desktop. I will make edits with linebreaks to make things easier. As I could gather I have two options. 1) Reinstall Packages Manually? ( How do I go about doing that? I tried for libc6 as I showed above is there any other way? ) 2)  Clean OS and Reinstall? Any other suggestions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to overwrite ... which is different from other instances of package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855474/trying-to-overwrite-which-is-different-from-other-instances-of-package)