Unable to repair broken packages in ubuntu 20.04
I have the following errors when I run this comma
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas alacarte gnome-applets gnome-applets-data
  gnome-panel gnome-panel-data gnome-screensaver gstreamer1.0-gtk3
  indicator-applet indicator-appmenu indicator-bluetooth indicator-datetime
  indicator-keyboard indicator-messages indicator-power indicator-printers
  indicator-session indicator-sound jayatana libabw-0.1-1 libaccounts-glib0
  libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libbamf3-2 libboost-date-time1.71.0
  libboost-filesystem1.71.0 libboost-iostreams1.71.0 libboost-locale1.71.0
  libclucene-contribs1v5 libclucene-core1v5 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcpufreq0
  libe-book-0.1-1 libeot0 libepubgen-0.1-1 libetonyek-0.1-1 libevent-2.1-7
  libexttextcat-2.0-0 libexttextcat-data libfcitx-gclient1 libfcitx-utils0
  libfreehand-0.1-1 libfreerdp-client2-2 libfreerdp2-2 libgnome-panel0
  libgpgmepp6 libgucharmap-2-90-7 libido3-0.1-0 libjuh-java libjurt-java
  liblangtag-common liblangtag1 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libmessaging-menu0
  libmhash2 libmspub-0.1-1 libmwaw-0.3-3 libmythes-1.2-0 libnatpmp1
  libneon27-gnutls libodfgen-0.1-1 liborcus-0.15-0 libpagemaker-0.0-0
  libpanel-applet3 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 libridl-java
  libunity-gtk2-parser0 libunity-gtk3-parser0 libuno-cppu3
  libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3
  libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 libunoloader-java liburl-dispatcher1 libvncclient1
  libwinpr2-2 libwps-0.4-4 libxmlsec1 libxmlsec1-nss libyajl2 lp-solve
  ubuntu-touch-sounds unity-gtk-module-common unity-gtk2-module
  unity-gtk3-module unity-settings-daemon-schemas uno-libs-private ure
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dbus dbus-x11 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386
  libavahi-common3:i386 libcom-err2:i386 libcups2:i386 libdbus-1-3
  libdbus-1-3:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libfribidi0:i386
  libgail-common:i386 libgail18:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgmp10:i386
  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhogweed5:i386
  libicu66:i386 libjbig0:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386
  libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblz4-1:i386 libnettle7:i386
  libnss-systemd libp11-kit0:i386 libpam-systemd libpcre2-8-0:i386
  libpcre3:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libssl1.1:i386 libsystemd0 libsystemd0:i386
  libtiff5:i386 libwebp6:i386 libxml2:i386 libzstd1:i386 systemd systemd-sysv
  systemd-timesyncd
Suggested packages:
  krb5-doc:i386 krb5-user:i386 librsvg2-common:i386 gvfs:i386
  systemd-container
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libsystemd0:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  dbus dbus-x11 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386
  libavahi-common3:i386 libcom-err2:i386 libcups2:i386 libdbus-1-3
  libdbus-1-3:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libfribidi0:i386
  libgail-common:i386 libgail18:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgmp10:i386
  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhogweed5:i386
  libicu66:i386 libjbig0:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386
  libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblz4-1:i386 libnettle7:i386
  libnss-systemd libp11-kit0:i386 libpam-systemd libpcre2-8-0:i386
  libpcre3:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libssl1.1:i386 libsystemd0 libtiff5:i386
  libwebp6:i386 libxml2:i386 libzstd1:i386 systemd systemd-sysv
  systemd-timesyncd
43 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
139 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/22.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,341 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 225599 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../liblz4-1_1.9.2-2ubuntu0.20.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking liblz4-1:i386 (1.9.2-2ubuntu0.20.04.1) over (1.9.2-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/liblz4-1_1.9.2-2ubuntu0.2
0.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/liblz4-1/changelog.Debian.gz', which
 is different from other instances of package liblz4-1:i386
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/liblz4-1_1.9.2-2ubuntu0.20.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


This question is similar to: dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in...". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your packages are not "broken" in the sense of being incomplete or corrupt. You have two packages that conflict (both want to install the same file). The system is simply asking you for a decision. How you tell the system your decision is explained in the duplicate.

This question is similar to: Trying to overwrite ... which is different from other instances of package. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This answer helped me! https://askubuntu.com/a/862436/676932
By removing the change-log file for LIBRARY :
sudo rm /usr/share/doc/LIBRARY/changelog.Debian.gz

Then:
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgarde

Because I had issue with many libraries, I deleted doc folder.

Try the following:
Open a terminal.
Run in it:
 sudo apt update

 sudo apt clean

 sudo apt autoremove

 sudo dpkg --configure -a

 sudo apt dist-upgrade

If you have any problems, please write a comment, not a question.

autoremove gives the following autput :
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
dbus-user-session : Depends: dbus (>= 1.12.16-2ubuntu2.3)
libavahi-client3 : Breaks: libavahi-client3:i386 (!= 0.7-4ubuntu7.3) but 0.7-4ubuntu7 is installed
.
.
.
libzstd1 : Breaks: libzstd1:i386 (!= 1.4.4+dfsg-3ubuntu0.1) but 1.4.4+dfsg-3 is installed
libzstd1:i386 : Breaks: libzstd1 (!= 1.4.4+dfsg-3) but 1.4.4+dfsg-3ubuntu0.1 is installed
netplan.io : Depends: systemd (>= 245.4-4ubuntu3.8)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
